# How to determine if the SQL Server running is Express version?

Tags: sql-server

is there a way to check whether the SQL Server I am connected is Express version?

How can I find how much space is left until the 10GB limit of the SQL Server Express?

Thank you!

Comment: You can execute "SELECT @@VERSION". Result will describe SQL Server version and edition.

Comment: Go to [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/) - the default first server is SQL Server running Express Edition. You can see how to get the version from the default first command (hint, it's what @RajeshRanjan wrote!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can execute `SELECT @@VERSION`. Result will describe SQL Server version and edition. Or `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')` will result SQL Server edition.

SQL Server Express Edition supports maximum database size 10GB per database. So you can monitor database size using following query.

```
SELECT      sys.databases.name,  
            CONVERT(VARCHAR,SUM(size)*8/1024)+' MB' AS [Total disk space]  
FROM        sys.databases   
JOIN        sys.master_files  
ON          sys.databases.database_id=sys.master_files.database_id  
GROUP BY    sys.databases.name  
ORDER BY    (SUM(size)*8/1024) DESC
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Rajesh!